# How to check if word in array exists in a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to create suggested tags, first i take input string while the user is typing, then check for words from a long list of words in an array, if word exists in the first array, check other arrays categories that this word falls into, then append some tag in an input.

**First Problem**: So far i can only check if a string contains a word, i don't know how to search an array so i can find words in a given string that match words in an array.

**Second Probelm**

After first word if found on keyup, any other keyup runs the script whereas i want it to wait for another second match.

**CODE HERE**

```
$(document).on('keyup','.Post_TextArea',function(){
    post_val = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val().length > 5){
        var string_g = 'tempo';
        var web_array = ['html', 'css', 'JavaScript'];
        var music_array = ['tempo', 'blues', 'rhythm'];
                if (post_val.toLowerCase().indexOf(string_g) >= 0){
                    if ($.inArray(string_g, web_array) !== -1){
                        $('.tags_holder').append('<span class="Tag_Style">Web</span>');
                    } else if ($.inArray(string_g, music_array) !== -1){
                        $('.tags_holder').append('<span class="Tag_Style">Music</span>');
                    } 
                    }
        }
    })
```

Comment: look at using **[filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** for first issue and match the strings in callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that you can do to solve your problem:

- Create re-usable components
- Ensure each function does a single task

Here's my take on the problem.

### Define your configuration

We can create a taxonomy for categorizing your words. In this case, we can group the words in an array and classify them by the key.

```
var taxonomy = {
    'web': ['html', 'css', 'javascript'],
    'music': ['tempo', 'blues', 'rhythm']
};
```

### Defined your function

Here we create two functions. What we want to achieve are:

- A predicate that checks for the word contained in the taxonomy
- Function that returns the classification of the words

Below is a predicate to check if a word is contained within a wordList. We can use this with our check on whether or not a word is a 'tagged' word.

```
function contains(wordList) {
    return function(word) {
        return (wordList.indexOf(word) > -1);
    };
};
```

Below is a function that returns the list of tags of words from the input. The key to this is using the `some()` function, which should be more light weight than the `filter()` function.

```
function getTags(input, taxonomy) {
    var words = input.match(/\w+/g);

    return Object.keys(taxonomy)
          .reduce(function(tags, classification) {
              var keywords = taxonomy[classification];
              if (words.some(contains(keywords)))
                  tags.push(classification);
              return tags;
          }, []);
};
```

### Connect to jQuery

Now that we have the core code, we can connect this to jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#tags').empty();
        var tags = getTags($(this).val(), taxonomy);
        tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            $('#tags').append($('<li>').text(tag));
        });
    });
});
```

#### Working Demo

See this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/8C9Dp/) for a live demo. Note: this should work only on IE9+, as the `some()`, `keys()`, and `forEach()` functions are not support in IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use a set of arrays, use a "map" instead - it's slightly less memory efficient but it's trivial to implement and very computationally efficient:

```
var tags = {
    'html': 'web', 'css': 'web', 'javascript': 'web',
    'tempo': 'music', 'blues': 'music', 'rhythm': 'music'
};

function suggestTags(input) {
    var result = { };
    var words = input.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
    words.forEach(function(word) {
        if (word in tags) {
            result[tags[word]]++;
        }
    }
    return Object.keys(result);
};
```

IMHO, an important point here is that the above is independent of any DOM manipulation.  You'll get cleaner code by separating your word searching from your DOM logic.

NB: some of the above uses ES5 functions - use a "shim" to support them in older browsers if required.